# Is the square root of $4$ only $+2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why is $4^{1/2}=+2$? 
It should also be $-2$ since both squared just give two only. Also why do we always represent root of $x$ on the right side of the number line?

Comment: It is an *Agreement*: in the real case, we *always* take the positive root. Among other reasons, to avoid confusion and to make $\,f(x)=\sqrt x\,\,,\,\,x\ge 0\,$ an actual function.

Comment: The square root function has two branches. You can consider the positive one or the negative one. So if you want negative values you should write $f(x)=-\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: You are confused with the idea of solving the equation x²=4 which is indeed 2,-2 Think about taking a squareroot as performing an operation on a number that gives uniquely another number.

Comment: "Also why do we always represent root of x on the right side of the number line?" Because the expression $\sqrt{-1}$ makes no sense if you restrict yourself to the real number line. Presumably you intended to say "Why do we represent root of $x$ *above* the number line?", which others have already addressed.

Comment: What you all mean to say is 4^(1/2)=2, also (-2)^2=4, but 4^(1/2)/=-2!

Comment: What I mean to say is that we should make root of x on both sides of number line, if y squared is x then -y squared is also x. Since we have -y and y they must be on both sides of number line.

Comment: @DonAntonio: It is actually wrong to state that without making the choice the definition would fail to be a function.  Although functions do indeed have only one output, that output can be a set or a group or any other mathematical structure.  Indeed, you could say outputting a Real number is actually outputting a Cauchy sequence, or a class of such sequences, or a Dedekind cut, .. which are themselves sets (or collections of such).  Choosing one value, though, does make it a real-valued function.

Comment: Rohinb97: what we are suggesting is that $y = \sqrt x$ is *not equivalent to* $y^2 = x$.

Comment: @ex0du5, I didn't say such a thing. I implied that if we do not agree on what real value to take in the real square root, two people working with the function "square root", assuming it is *already* a function, can get pretty different values, even if restricted to real numbers. Now, somebody already mentioned branches and stuff, which seems to be way over the level of somebody asking such a basic question.

Comment: @amWhy: I didn't mention branches.  I simply corrected the incorrect idea that you choose a single value to make $f(x)$ "an actual function".  I'm not trying to complicate things - I'm trying to prevent misuse of mathematical language.  A function to a set is an actual function.  Notice I didn't correct your post because you actually mentioned "real function" and one could argue the latter half of that sentence referred to the same type of function.

Comment: No...I didn't mean you, @ex0du5 (there was another comment above that did)...I understand your point fully! ;-)

Comment: Many high school teachers would write $\sqrt{4}=\pm 2$. They are not really wrong. Just speaking a different language.

Comment: It's a very VERY different language, I am afraid. I hope their language uses a different symbol for our square root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is **by convention**: with real numbers, we agree to take the ***positive*** square root. This allows us to define $$f(x) = \sqrt x, \;\;x \in \mathbb R, \;\;x\geq 0, $$ so it is a *true* real-valued function: taking a square-root of a number greater than or equal to zero "returns" a *unique* real number (is hence a function). Without that convention $\sqrt x$ would *fail to be* be a function.

(Note: as imranfat suggests: I think you might be confusing the square root *function* with what we know about solving an *equation* $x^2 = 4$, which has two solutions, $x = \pm 2$.