# Graph of the $\sqrt { x } $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does the graph only go to the right and up? Wouldn't there be negative values of y as well? Since, for example, the $\sqrt{4}$ is $2$ and $-2$

Comment: When you graph $\sqrt{x}$, you're graphing a function; a function can only have one $y$ for each $x$. If you graphed $x=y^2$ or $y=\pm\sqrt{x}$ then both $2$ & $-2$ would be points at $x=4$ (though this wouldn't be a function). In my opinion, the notation should be more specific but without using $|\sqrt{x}|$, there doesn't seem to be anything else.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408104/is-the-square-root-of-4-only-2?rq=1, which is, in turn, a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158566/is-it-wrong-to-say-sqrtx-times-sqrtx-pm-x-forall-x-in-mathbbr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graph of $y=\sqrt{x}$ is goes only right up since:

- there are no negative values of $x$ allowed
- there are no negative values of $y$ allowed (since $\sqrt{x}$ can never be negative)

Furthermore: $\sqrt{4}=2$, but $\sqrt{4}\ne-2$. You are confused with: $(-2)^2=2^2=4$.

Comment: Is this basically implying that you can only use the principal square root for functions?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer  A function can only have one output for every input.  So, if I plug in $2$ and get $-\sqrt{2}$ and $+\sqrt{2}$, it's no longer a function.

Comment: With that being said, couldn't this be graphed going in the opposite direction on the y axis? Using the negative square root..

Comment: It could, but then it wouldn't be *one* function, but *two* functions: $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $g(x)=-\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: So the "rule" of the function would have to explicitly ask for the negative square root in order for the graph of the function to go in a negative direction?

Comment: Exactly. The graph would then lie in the left bottom of the coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

- $\sqrt{x}$ is defined only when $x\ge 0$.
- For any $x\ge 0$, $\sqrt x\ge 0$. So, $\sqrt{4}=\sqrt{2^2}=2$ (not $-2).$

Answer (score 1):

A *function* $f$ is a map $f: X\rightarrow Y$ which for every input $x\in X$ gives precisely one output $f(x)\in Y$. Taking $\sqrt4=\pm2$ is *not* a function, because it has two outputs.

The notation $\sqrt{x}$ is used to denote the function $\sqrt{\:\:\:}\:: \mathbb{R}^{+}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{+}$ with positive image, ignoring the negative numbers which are square roots. When you graph $\sqrt{x}$, you are graphing this function.

Answer (score 1):

A function y is an output of certain operation over a variable, say x, such that it should give a unique value for any value of x. But, function can give same value for two different values of x. In a general sense, $ \sqrt{} $ is not a function, because for a single value of x, two values for y are obtained for example $$\sqrt{16} = \pm 4$$. In order to make it a function, appropriate domain for x and y are chosen such that $f:x \rightarrow y $ such that where $\sqrt{}$ is the function f with $x \in R^{+}$ and  $y \in R^{+}$. Then, the graph mentioned in the question is obtained i.e curve on the right and up side of the coordinate system. 

  If the domain of y is defined as $ y \in R^{-} $ and domain of x remains same, then the curve would on right and downside of conventional coordinate system. If the function f maps such $\sqrt{}:x \rightarrow y$ for $x\in R^{-}$, then y have to be defined in complex plane such as to make $\sqrt{}$ as a function i.e to give unique value of y.

> If the same relation between x and y is taken in reverse sense i.e $g:y \rightarrow x$ such that $x = g(y)=y^2$ here squaring is the function with $y \in R$ and $x \in R^{+} $. It is the equation of parabola rotated with its concave side towards positive x-axis as shown in the following figure.
>   
>   [image: lazy dog]

Answer (score 0):

Because $x^2$ is not one to one in real numbers. Look at the general definition of function, and it will be clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common misconception:
$x^2 = 4$ means that $x=2$ or $x=-2$, HOWEVER, we never actually take the square root to find these solutions.

The square root is a "function" ($\sqrt\  :\mathbb{R^+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R})$ - and a "function" only has one input for the input you give it.